# How to generate a json array from a table data inside a <td> tag

Tags: php, jquery, json, html-table

I am trying to get those data in the JSON format. Would you please help me to generate that? Please help I am not very familiar with jquery and php.

html code looks like this

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>//some code for other table elements</td><tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Critical Times (Coverage): </td>
            <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">
                <div>
                    <table width="100%" bgcolor="white" border="0px" name="criticalTime" id="criticalTime">
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="timeAdd" value="+"/><br>
                <input type="button" id="timeRemove" value="-"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>//some code for other table elements</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

my .js file has the following to handle the addition of rows to the table when click the + button.

```
var rowCountr = 0;
var timeTable="<thead><tr bgcolor='E1ECFF'><th></th><th align='left'>Start Time</th><th align='left'>End Time</th></tr></thead>";
/* insert the html string*/
$("#criticalTime").html( timeTable );

/*Event for the +(Add) button in critical time table*/
var timeRwcntr=0;
timeRow="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' id='row'</td><td><input type='text' id='start' /></td><td><input type='text' id='end'/></td></tr>";       

$('#timeAdd').click(function(){
    $('#criticalTime').append(timeRow);
    rowCountr++;
    timeRwcntr++;
}); 
$('#timeRemove').click(function(){
    $('#criticalTime tr:last-child').remove();
});
```

When I click the submit button from main form I need to get those values entered in the input fields and generate an JSON array to store those in database. Please help.

Comment: Please format your code in a more legible manner, it makes it easier for all of us to read.  You will be more likely to get help.  thanks :)

Comment: Answered Here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034103/serialize-inputs-in-table-rows-jquery

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I think that JSON may be overkill. You're just trying to send your table's input fields back to the server on a postback right? When you create your table rows, add a uniquely identifying number in the "name" attribute of your form controls `<input name="'.$id.'_field" />` for example if you are rendering the table server-side; the code would be similar for javascript. Then, when you post back, you can loop through each row by counting and then access the POST variable you got back by referencing the name. Example:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $rowcount; $i++) {
    $field_value = $_POST[$i.'_field'];
    ...
}
```

JSON is great for more complex data sets, but in your case it sounds like you have structured two-dimensional rows and columns.